# How to extract just one of classes of object with multiple classes

Tags: r, class, tidyverse, tibble, r-haven

Say I have a tibble named `a'. It has three classes:

```
class(a)

"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

How can I extract just one of these classes?

```
a$data.frame
```

does not work.

Another example is a `haven_labelled` object, `b` which has three classes:

```
class(b)
"haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"
```

How can I extract just the double part of `b`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class()` results in an unnamed character vector, which you usually subset using numeric indeces `x[i]`, e.g. `class(b)[3]` to obtain `double"`.

However you could apply string matching, and write an own `my_class()` function which is based on a vector of *valid* class definitions.

```
valid <- c("data.frame", "double", "character")

my_class <- function(x) {k <- class(x);k[k %in% valid]}

my_class(a)
# [1] "data.frame"

my_class(b)
# [1] "double"
```

---

*Data:*

```
a <- tibble::as_tibble(data.frame())
b <- haven::labelled()
```